# what to change on php code to submit form with onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">SUBMIT</a>?

Tags: php, forms, mailer

Two problems with a php mailer :

The 1st one 
• Mailer does not work with :

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">SUBMIT</a>
```

• It uses to work well with :

```
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="send" class="submitbutton"/>
```

If I replace the button by the above input then it works.

However I have never used it with radiobuttons before : the form is submitted but radiobuttons are not processed which is trouble number 2 in this post;
The script seems to be created for multi alternative checkboxes and not for selective radiobutton.

What has to be changed to accomodate both submit button and radiobuttons ?

FORM

```
<form  class="form-1" id="form" method="POST" action="php/subscription.php">
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="phone">
<input type="text" id="email">

<input type="checkbox" name="check[ ]" value="iwhishtoreceivemailing" >  WITH CHECKBOX VALUES ARE SUBMITTED  

<input type="radio" name="check[   ]" id="">  ?????????????  don´t know how to change the code for radiobuttons

<input type="text" id="message">

  <a class="button" href="javascript:" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">SUBMIT</a>


how to make it work with this php script ??




MAILER.PHP (php code is pasted below)
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$to = "anything@whatever.com ";
$to2 = "johndoe@jackfrost.com"; 
$subject = "contact_form";
                    $name = $_POST['visitor_name'];
                    $phone = $_POST['one'];
                    $email  = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        foreach( (array)$_POST['check'] as $value){
    $check_msg .= "Checked: $value\n";
} 

        $body = "Name: $name\n phone: $phone\n Email : $email\n Mailing: $iwhishtoreceivemailing\n Message: $message\n";

        header("Location: thankyoupage.html");
        mail($to, $subject, $body );
        mail($to2, $subject, $body);

} else {
        echo "error_invalid_function";
```

Comment: Your first code example is broken. Verify you write all attribute values right, look for `"` (quotes). Take care.

Answer (score 2):

instead of :

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
```

do :

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
```

because submit button that have name `Submit`does not exsite any more

Comment: @RonWolpa do you get any error, if you're working in local `mail()` function will not work